# NetLogo: set pcolor of random patches in specific distance from center

Tags: distance, netlogo

I am pretty new in NetLogo and I would like to **create patchy world surface, where patches (yellow) are in different distances from central patch** (dashed red circles).

More specifically, I want to **select 3 random patches at distances: 10, 20, 30 patches from central patch and turn them yellow**. I'm sure it is pretty simple to do that but I'm not able to figure out the right utilization of distance measure.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated !

```
to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
end

to setup-patches
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor green ]
  ask patch 0 0
  [ 
    set pcolor yellow                 
    ask patches in-radius 10 [set pcolor yellow] ; how to include distance here??
  ]
  ask n-of 5 patches [ set pcolor yellow] ; or here ??
end
```

[image: expected result]

Comment: That's a great question. Having the image really helps to understand what you're trying to achieve. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trickier than it looks! You'd think you'd be able to just use [`distance`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#distance):

```
foreach [ 10 20 30 40 ] [
  ask n-of 3 patches with [ distance patch 0 0 = ? ] [
    set pcolor yellow
  ]
]
```

But here is the result if we drop the `n-of 3` to get all the patches at each distance to turn yellow:

[image]

The problem is that it looks for patch at the *exact* distance specified.

Maybe you could just give it a little bit of tolerance, then?

```
foreach [ 10 20 30 40 ] [
  ask patches with [
    distance patch 0 0 > ? - 0.5 and
    distance patch 0 0 < ? + 0.5
  ] [
    set pcolor yellow
  ]
]
```

This is better, but still not *quite* right. Some part of the circles are thicker than other:

[image]

But maybe it's good enough for your purpose, or you could tweak the tolerance a bit.

Finally, here is a wacky way of achieving a similar result:

```
to-report circle-at [ d ]
  let dummies []
  let circle []
  create-turtles 2 [
    set dummies lput self dummies
  ]
  ask last dummies [
    setxy 0 d
    create-link-with first dummies [ tie ]
  ]
  repeat 3600 [
    ask first dummies [
      right 0.1
      ask last dummies [
        set circle lput patch-here circle
      ]
    ]
  ]
  ask turtle-set dummies [ die ]
  report patch-set circle
end
```

It uses the [`tie`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#tie) command to have one turtle turn around another and add the patches that it traverses to our result set. It's slow, but it works, and you get a nice smooth circle:

[image]

Using this procedure, your final code would be:

```
foreach [ 10 20 30 40 ] [
  ask n-of 3 circle-at ? [
    set pcolor yellow
  ]
]
```

Comment: Wow ! Thank you @Nicolas Payette! I'll never figure it out, it is really tricky... But it works fine now.

Comment: Yeah, maybe there is a better, simpler way that I didn't think of. But I'm glad it works for you!

Comment: I've added another answer that's the simplest thing I can think of. But Nicolas, I love your crazy `tie`-based solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more alternative:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor green ]
  foreach [10 20 30] [
    repeat 3 [
      make-yellow-patch ?
    ]
  ]
end

to make-yellow-patch [dist]
  create-turtles 1 [
    rt random-float 360
    fd dist
    while [pcolor = yellow] [
      bk dist
      rt random-float 360
      fd dist
    ]
    set pcolor yellow
    die
  ]
end
```

sample results:

[image: view]

```
observer> show sort [round distancexy 0 0] of patches with [pcolor = yellow ]
observer: [10 10 10 19 20 20 30 30 30]
```

I don't think the 19 is a bug. As Nicolas shows, you don't want to favor any particular part of the circle, so that means you have to allow some variation in the distance.

Comment: Thank you @Seth Tisue! it seems to work :) and I don't really need the exactly same distance from the centered patch and some variation will be contributive :)